# Change Marker Image Source Dynamically

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using the "react-native-maps" npm package in my React Native application.

I am trying to change the marker image source dynamically. 

I am able to reference the specific marker via an instance variable (this.markers), however I am unable to make any changes to it. 


Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<MapView
    style={styles.mapView}
    initialRegion={this.initialRegion}
    ref={ref => this.mapView = ref}
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    showsUserLocation={true}
    showsCompass={true}
    showsScale={true}
>
    {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => {
        <MapView.Marker
            image={require("../../assets/images/marker.png")}
            key={`marker-${index}`}
            coordinate={marker.coordinate}
            ref={ref => this.markers[`marker-${index}`] = ref}
        >
        </MapView.Marker>
    })}
</MapView>
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: you need to change all of them or just specific items ?

Comment: only a specific one.